# Cannot set session ID after the session has started when posting a form while running a test

Tags: php, symfony, session, phpunit, functional-testing

As mentioned in the title this error only occurs when posting a form through the `WebTestCase` functional test of Symfony.

I'm trying to functional test some controllers by loading their index and then posting some data to the form on that page. Every time I try to post, i receive the "**Cannot set session ID after the session has started**" error.

I'm using Symfony 2.8.9 but I can't find any answers on the internet.

```
class CheckoutTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $client;

    public function setUp()
    {
        include_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../../web/constants.inc.php');
        include_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../../app/config/environment.php');

        $this->client = static::makeClient(true, array(
            'HTTP_HOST' => 'dev.myshop.com',
        ));
    }

    public function testStep1()
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/contact/');
        $this->assertEquals(200, $this->client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Submit')->form();
        $this->client->submit($form);

        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
```

My config_test.yml file:

```
framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
```

My phpunit.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
     backupGlobals="false"
     processIsolation="false"
     colors="true"
     bootstrap="autoload.php"
>
<php>
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    <ini name="intl.default_locale" value="en" />
    <ini name="intl.error_level" value="0" />
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1" />
</php>

<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
        <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us the controller action for the `/contact/` route?

Comment: @EmanuelOster the problem occurs on every page holding a form, let me see if I can get a really simple example.